# Can someone explain strange results of SQL (Sub-)Query on InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb, flux, influxdb-2, influxql

In my influx db I have wrong data I need to update. Therefore I am looking for spikes in my data and I am using OFFSET and LIMIT in a divide and conquer algorithm to find this spikes.

Now I have strange results, that prevent my code/ queries from beeing successful. I hope you can help me.

This query gives me the following results:
`SELECT MAX(value) FROM (SELECT value FROM My_Measurement LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1882381)`

```
| Time                 | max      |
| -------------------- | -------- |
| 2020-01-18 08:40:05  |   57.843 |
```

When I just execute the sub-query, it gives me totally different results which are several years later:
`SELECT value FROM My_Measurement LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1882381`

```
| Time                 | max      |
| -------------------- | -------- |
| 2023-05-06 05:25:05  |  541.173 |
| 2023-05-06 05:26:05  |  541.173 |
```

So how can this be? Whats my error?

Well, I would expect, that the select MAX (or MIN) on the subquery would give me the Max/Min of the values returned by the subquery.

I am using InfluxDB v2.7.0 (git: 85f725f8b9) build_date: 2023-04-05T15:32:38Z (upgraded from 1.7 to 2.0.3 to 2.7.0)

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any more information?

Answer (score 0):

Influx can't handle subqueries with a LIMIT.
This issue is present in both Influxv1 and v2. It has been reported multiple times already (since 2018), but keeps getting ignored.

- https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/10253
- https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/24089
- https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/24622